# Error when updating Heroku CLI: write lock exists: update

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-cli

I am trying to update the Heroku CLI, however, without success.

Current version of Heroku CLI is

```
heroku-cli/6.15.5-1f03166 (win32-x64) node-v9.3.0
```

When running

```
heroku update
```

I get the following error

[image]

```
C:\>heroku update
CLI is updating... !
 !    'ELOCK': write lock exists: update
```

I didnt' find any solution to this problem so far as I am hesitating to just uninstall and re-install the Heroku CLI (all my configs are lost then).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by uninstalling heroku and installing via command line:
 `npm install -g heroku`
So I got the most current version.

Comment: Installing via npm is discouraged by Heroku though: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-with-npm

Answer (score 1):

Updating heroku worked for me:

```
npm update -g heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the cause of this was but restarting solved the issue for me. Good luck!

```
11:53:26 | ~  : heroku update
heroku-cli: Updating CLI from 6.15.26-5726b6f to 6.15.30-e7b41cd... 
done
Updating plugins, node version changed to 9.7.1... done
heroku-cli: Updating plugins... done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved removing this file:

`/Users/YOUR_USER/Library/Caches/heroku/update.lock`

I use mac, but I guess you will have same file in a similar location

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the Mac - solved it by running `htop`, filtering by `heroku` and killing all processes.

TLDR; kill running Heroku processes

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and solved it by removing `error.log` from the following directory in Windows 10: `C:\Users\Behzad\.heroku\error.log`