# How do I update Heroku Buildpack on Terminal?

Tags: macos, heroku, terminal, web

I am having a difficult time pushing my app to Heroku. 
Please see http://www.kristingumbert.com/ for the error message.

In addition: I need to update my Heroku Buildpack but can not figure out how to do so in my terminal.

```
 $ heroku buildpacks
 ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.15.26-5726b6f to 6.99.0-ec9edad
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ heroku update
CLI is updating... !
 ▸    'ELOCK': write lock exists: update
```

[Error when updating Heroku CLI: write lock exists: update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348054/error-when-updating-heroku-cli-write-lock-exists-update)

Comment: Is this an update to your question or an answer to your question? Please clarify how the solution helped your problem.